# How to add a "$" as part of a Read-Host prompt

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Sorry my question might be oddly worded. What I want to do is have a dollar sign after my Read-Host prompt. So what I currently have is:

```
$BookPrice = Read-Host "Please enter book price"
```

When this command is executed, it looks like:

```
Please enter book price:
```

What I want the command to look like is:

```
Please enter book price: $
```

So that the user can just input a price starting from the "$". I've tried a bunch of things, but the dollar sign always ends up before the colon.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @jww why would this go on SuperUser? OP is looking for a programmic way to have read host set a default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way, as 2 commands:

```powershell
Write-Host 'Please enter book price: $' -NoNewline
$BookPrice = Read-Host
```

Comment: Wonder if the OP wanted the $ as part of the return.... either way never occurred to try that. Good call

Comment: Hm, my interpretation was that he or she did not want the `$` as part of the return value, but that's easy enough to work in using concatenation before the `Read-Host` as you did in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly. Thank you briantist!

And yeah my primary concern was getting the "$" after the colon within the Read-Host text.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to start of the user with some text. I dont think that is realistically possible with Read-Host natively. Someone could easily prove me wrong. Would a prefix in the return value work for this case?

```
PS C:\Users\Name> $BookPrice = '$' + (Read-Host 'Please enter book price')
Please enter book price: 345
PS C:\Users\Name> $BookPrice
$345
```

You could throw in a little `If` to catch if the user actually put a $ so and to not create a duplicate. If you are willing to step out of console you could do this with an input box.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$BookPrice = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please enter book price", "Book Price", '$')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I tried both methods and they both contain the dollar sign before the colon when executed

Comment: Oh i misread the question. I don't think that you can really do that. I gave a silly workaround for an answer

Comment: Not a problem and thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I had to find a solution within the console, but that's very interesting. Thanks again for all the help!